# On the use of 「憎々しいまでの」

Tags: nuances

The usage seems straightforward in such cases as:

> ドラマやアニメでは悪役として登場する事が多く、この場合は**憎々しいまでの演技と性格づけ**が重要となる。<sup>[1](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BD%E4%B8%8A%E5%8F%B8)</sup>

↑ the performance is so good that the bad character appears almost 「憎々しい」.

But sometimes I feel kind of uncertain of its nuance as in:

> 力石は死んだのではなく、見失われたのであり、それは七〇年の時代感情の**憎々しいまでの的確な反映**であるというほかはないだろう。<sup>[2](http://www.osk.3web.ne.jp/~nanten/syowa/text/rikiishi.html)</sup>

↑ How can the reflection be so to the point that it feels even 「憎々しい」?

> 本日の天気は快晴、雲一つない**憎々しいまでの晴天**だ。<sup>[3](http://www.pixiv.net/novel/show.php?id=5324901)</sup>

↑ How can the weather be so good that it is almost 「憎々しい」?

> 好きな食べ物は？**憎々しいまでの肉**！<sup>[4](http://profile.ameba.jp/xxx-madhead-ad2xxx/)</sup>

↑ You like the meat so much that it turns 「憎々しい」?

To wrap it up, can 「憎々しいまでの」 be used as a generic emphasizer even when there are actually no real 「憎々しい」 feelings involved? That is, similar to the Mandarin phrase 「[要死](http://www.zdic.net/c/1/162/360177.htm)」.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[憎々しい](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166558/meaning/m0u/) in a dictionary:

> いかにも憎らしい。非常に憎らしい。

So let's jump to [憎らしい](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166585/meaning/m0u/):

> **２** 気にさわるほどすばらしい。にくい。

So "vexingly excellent" (or practically, *astonishingly excellent*) is the meaning. 憎い and its derivatives including 憎らしい, 憎たらしい and 小憎い all share this definition. Your example #2 is explained in this way.

But for your #3:

> 本日の天気は快晴、雲一つない憎々しいまでの晴天だ。**やけにうっとうしい日差しが肌を焼く。**

He's complaining about the scorching-hot sun, so he probably literally "hates" it.

And your #4:

> 憎々しいまでの肉

reads にくにくしいまでのにく. Yeah, it's a pun. This is a slang also written as [肉肉しい](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E8%82%89%E8%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84) to describe a meal contains a lot of juicy meat, or "[meatful](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=meatful)".

Answer (score 1):

＃日本語
「憎々しいまでの的確な反映であるというほかはないだろう。」
この評論家はこの作品の欠点を指摘して評論家として自己の価値をアピールしたいのに、この作品が非の打ちどころもないほど的確なので、すなわち欠点を見いだせないので憎たらしい。よって「憎々しい」と表現したと思われます。ただし、この評論家はこの作品を大変好意的にほめていると思います。

「憎々しいまでの晴天だ。」とは、日本語ではあまり言ったり（、聞いたり、書いたり）しません。また、「憎々しいまでの肉」は語呂合わせとしてはおもしろいですが、絶対に言いません。「憎々しいまでおいしい肉」という表現は「憎々しいまでの晴天だ。」と同程度で表現が許されるかもしれませんが、このような表現で肉のおいしさを形容することはほどんどなく、私なら、別の形容詞を使います。

後半の２つの例文に関して、「憎々しい」という形容詞を使わないと言いましたが、それは、「憎々しい」という形容詞は、人に関わる状況を皮肉って表現するのには適しているが、天気や食べ物といった自然物を形容するのに向いていないと思うからです。

## English

「憎々しいまでの的確な反映であるというほかはないだろう。」
Although this critic wants to appeal his own value as a critic by pointing out the drawbacks of this work, this work is so precise as not to be impatient, that is, it is hateful because he can not find any fault at all. Therefore it seems that he expressed as 「憎々しい hatred」. However, I think that this critic praises this work very favorably.

I don't say/hear/write much in Japanese as 「憎々しいまでの晴天だ」. Although the expression 「憎々しいまでの肉」 is interesting as a play on words or a pun, I'll never say that. Although the expression 「憎々しいまでおいしい肉」 may be allowed to be expressed at the same degree as 「憎々しいまでの晴天だ。」, it is not possible to express the delicious taste of the meat with such expression as 「憎々しい」. I would use another adjective instead.

As for the latter two senteces, I said the adjective 「憎々しい」don't match them. I think that the adjective 「憎々しい」has nuance of a cracking joke relating to the things of human, therefor it does not match expressing natural things such as climate or food.