# Meaning of い adjective + までの + noun

Tags: grammar, particle-まで

I'm working on translating a script for a SNES game and have run into this grammar in the following sentences:

ナガサキの家で おまえの両親を 我々が殺した時の あの すさまじいまでのパワー あの時おまえは まだ たったの４さい・・・

オレ達 ゾク世間から 遠くはなれた あの神々しいまでの うつくしさ・・・

I've tried checking some grammar dictionaries & textbooks but haven't had any luck finding this so far. I was only ever taught that a noun or a verb could come before まで, so I'm not sure what's supposed to be the difference in meaning here compared to just い adjective + noun.

Comment: Just curious, which SNES game is this?

Comment: Kind of related [On the use of 「憎々しいまでの」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/)

Comment: @cmw The game is "Day of the Idea" (イデアの日).

Comment: Very cool. I'm always a fan of new translations from SFC (etc.) games, so good to see. Hadn't seen this one before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what's supposed to be the difference in meaning here compared to just い adjective + noun.

Practically, there's not much difference and I think, in terms of translation, you can forget までの: *tremendous power* / *divine beauty*.

The usage of まで is mentioned, e.g., in the following questions (the second one is similar in usage, but separate).

- [How does まで work in ～なまでの／～なまでに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27517)
- [Figuring out what 「言わないまでも」means in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73336/45489)

Literally XなまでにA means *A to the point of being X* and XなまでのN is the corresponding noun. As something that works naturally, 神々しいまでの美しさ is a nominal form of 神々しいまでに美しい=beautiful to the point of being divine, and means *beauty that is almost divine*.

In terms of usage, it is a kind of rhetoric to emphasize the degree of 'A'(or corresponding 'N'). In a case like すさまじいまでのパワー, I guess it can be only *terrible/tremendous/gigantic power* translationwise.